# Polymer : Property 'response' bound to attribute 'last-response' not found in 'properties' for element 'menu-kaart'

Tags: polymer

I'm working on a project in polymer and while I was busy, I get this error:

> Property 'response' bound to attribute 'last-response' not found in 'properties' for element 'menu-kaart'

Since I am new to polymer, I don't know what to do. I searched over the internet and I can't find the solution.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">


<dom-module id="menu-kaart">

<template>
<style>
  :host {
      display: block;
      background-color: maroon;
      padding: 15px;
      color: deepskyblue;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }


    h1 {
      color: antiquewhite;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    h3, p {
      color: antiquewhite;
    }

    div {
      color: white;
    }        
</style>

<iron-ajax 
  auto 
  url="/cgi-bin/menulezen.py" 
  handle-as="json" 
  last-response="{{response}}">
  </iron-ajax>
    <h1>Menukaart</h1>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
    <div>
        <h3>{{item.Gerecht}}</h3>
        <p>Ingredienten: {{item.Ingredienten}} <br>
        Opmerkingen: {{item.Opmerkingen}}</p>
    </div>
  </template>
```

```
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
is: 'menu-kaart',
properties: {

}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try adding property `response` in properties object of `menu-kaart`

Comment: no i didnt do that

Comment: You should try it. By the way what version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.17.0

Comment: Are you sure? The snippet that you have pasted above is of `Polymer 1.x` and not `Polymer 0.x`.

Comment: when i type 'polymer --version' in cmd than thats what i get back

Comment: Check `bower.json` file of Polymer folder in `bower_components`

Comment: In the file it sais that the version is 1.3.1

Comment: And on which browser are you testing your code?

Comment: im using firefox

Comment: Ideally you should not be facing this issue as `Polymer 1.x` allows properties to be used even without mentioning them in `properties` object. This will change only from `2.x`. Did adding it in properties object fix your problem?

Comment: i didnt do anything yet. i dont know what en how to add in the properties object

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `script` tag to

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'menu-kaart',
    properties: {
       response: {
          type: Object
       }
    }
</script>
```

I'd also recommend you to upgrade your Polymer version to latest 1.x i.e. 1.8 or something relatively newer as Polymer has done a lot of fixes/changes since 1.3.

Lastly, i'll recommend you to read some [documentations](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview) or some video tutorials to have a better understanding of Polymer